# menu with submenu using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, submenu

Hello I just a little but help.

What I am trying to do is create a menu with a submenu by getting the data from 2 different mysql tables.

The issue I am having is the submenu will not display all results from the "Sub Category" database depending on what page I am on

Table 1: Category "ID, Name"

Table 2: Sub Category "ID, Name, Cparent, filename (Image for sub category)"

I have the following code:

```
<ul>
<?php 
  $catmenu_sql = 'select category.id AS catid, category.name AS catname, scategory.cparent AS    scparent, scategory.name AS scname
from category
left join scategory on category.id = scategory.cparent
group by category.name'; // Select data from database
      $result = mysql_query($catmenu_sql); 

while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>

<!-- Begin Category list -->
<li class="menu">
    <a href="category.php?id=<?php echo $rows['catid']; ?>" id="<?php echo $rows['catid']; ?>" class="menu"><?php echo($rows['catname']); ?></a>
</li>
<!-- End Category List -->   

<?php 
    if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) // get the 'id' variable from the URL and match it with scategory parent in database
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sid = $rows['scparent'];
    if ( $id == $sid ) {
?>

<!-- Begin Sub Category List -->    
<ul>
<li class="menu"><a href="scategory.php?id= <?php echo $rows['catid']; ?>" id=" <?php echo $rows['catid'];?>"class="smenu"><?php echo $rows['scname']; ?></a>
    </li>
</ul>
<!-- End Sub category List -->
<?php }} ?>
</ul>'
```

Any help  will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Down-voted due to poor quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try replace your code with this

```
<?php 

$catmenu_sql = 'select category.id AS catid, category.name AS catname, scategory.cparent AS scparent, scategory.name AS scname
               from category
               left join scategory on category.id = scategory.cparent
               group by category.name'; // Select data from database

$result = mysql_query($catmenu_sql); 


$sHTML="<ul>";

while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{ 

    $sHTML="<ul>"

    <!-- Begin Category list -->
    $sHTML .= '<li class="menu">' .
              '<a href="category.php?id=' . $rows['catid'] . ' id=' . $rows['catid'] . ' class="menu">' . $rows['catname'] .'</a>' .
              '</li>' ;
    <!-- End Category List -->  


    $subquery = "SELECT sec_name FROM tbl_user_sec WHERE `sec_group` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($row_secs['sec_group'] . "'";
    $subresult = mysql_query($subquery);

    <!-- Begin Sub Category List -->  
    if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) // get the 'id' variable from the URL and match it with scategory parent in database
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sid = $rows['scparent'];
    if ( $id == $sid ) 
       {

        $sHTML .="<ul>";

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($subresult) ) {        

              $sHTML .= '<li class="menu"><a href="scategory.php?id= ' . $rows['catid'] . ' id=' . $rows['catid'] . ' class="smenu">' . $rows['scname'] . '</a>' .
                        '</li>' ;
            }

        $sHTML .="</ul>";
        }
    <!-- End Sub category List --> 


 } 

$sHTML .= '</ul>'
echo $sHTML
?>
```

Comment: Hello @matzone I have tried the above code. I did get a couple errors which a managed to sort out but its still shows exactly the same as before. What happends is I can get the category's out the database fine, Its when I click on one of the category's I am only getting the 1st subcategory out of the database even though in some category's they have more then one sub category. I hope this makes sence. Here is the website address (Only a temp address and its not spam or anything like that) http://newshop.webatu.com/category.php?id=5

Comment: hello @matzone sorry if am being thick but what do I need to put on line $subquery = "SELECT sec_name FROM tbl_user_sec WHERE `sec_group` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($row_secs['sec_group'] . "'"; thanks for your help

Comment: It looks as though I have sort this out now finaly :D I would like to thank you @matzone

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem correctly, this line:

```
if ( $id == $sid ) {
```

filters the sub categories depending of the page you're, given that `$id` is being initialized as:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

which is the value of a parameter named `id` that is being passed to the url, possibly like this:

```
http://www.site.com/script.php?id=1
```

that's what making you see only a sub set of the categories, to see them all you should not pass the id parameter to the url.

Comment: I do not think your answer is something he can understand.

Comment: Yes the '$id = $_GET['id'];' gets the ID number from  the '?id=1' in the url. Once I have the ID of the page I then put in '$sid = $rows['scparent'];' which will get the ID from the database. Once I have both ID's I then need to match them to the correct line in the table to get the correct row. I am able to get the 1st list from the "Category" ok it just when I try and pull the sub menu it will only give me one result from the "Sub category" table

Comment: Thanks @Rafael So how would I be able to define what page you are on to get the correct results from table if I don't pass the ID to the URL? Sorry if am not making much sense as I am still learning.

Comment: Seeing your page I understand better now, I can't find any obvious errors in your code, but I would recommend you to check if your query really returns what it's supposed to, try running your code by hand and see if you spot why it's not working.

Comment: Make sure to sanitize $_GET['id']